# Renci.SshNet C# Connect method works on loopback but timesout on all other IP addresses

Tags: c#

I've got a very simple SSH connection that I'm trying to build in c# with VS2019 using renci.sshnet. When connecting to 127.0.0.1 the code connects flawlessly, but changing the ip address to connect to the local machine or a LAN server fails with a time out "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

The firewall and network seem correctly configured, all connections when tried from commandline using the windows 10 open ssh client work. I've tried connecting to a linux ssh server as well as local machine and lan hosted windows open ssh servers. It doesn't seem that my code is even trying to connect, incorrect passwords, non existant IP addresses all give the same timeout errors. Yet the loopback address executes perfectly. I'm at a loss. Any help would be dearly appreciated. The code of the simple console app is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Renci.SshNet;

namespace TestTunnel2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
            string user = "TestUser";
            string pswd = "TestPassword";
           ipAddress = "198.162.0.57";

            SshClient myClient = new SshClient(ipAddress, user, pswd);

            Console.WriteLine("Trying connection to "+ipAddress);
            try
            {
                myClient.Connect();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected: " + myClient.IsConnected);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "198.162.0.57"? Maybe "192.168.0.57"?

Comment: I was banging my head on the wall after this...Thank you, this was it. Why a timeout vs unreachable was a question that came to mind... Thanks again, such a ridiculous mistake, sigh.